# Convert dynamic JSON key value in single field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, type-conversion

How do I dynamically parse the JSON array and store single JSON Key values in one field using JavaScript.

I have a JSON array

```
let newList=
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small"},
{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000"},
{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock"}];
```

And I want to parse them so that a new field Description will be added to show as-

```
newList=
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small",
"Description":"Name: House 1 \n Type: Small"},

{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000",
"Description":"Name: House 2 \n Type: Big \n Rent: 3000"},

{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock",
"Description":"Name: House 3 \n Owner: Rock"}];
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). You have an array of objects. Hence -> [Working with Objects | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)

Comment: If the content of `description` has to be actual JSON, then -> `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the value you're storing in `newList` is not valid JSON (JSON is text), you can achieve what you want by performing a three step process:

1. Parse your JSON string
2. Modify the resulting object
3. Stringify the modified object to a new JSON

```
let newList= `
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small"},
{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000"},
{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock"}]
`
const parsedList = JSON.parse(newList);
const modifiedParsedList = transform(parsedList);
const resultingJson = JSON.stringify(modifiedParsedList );


function transform(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    const Description = Object.entries(item)
        .reduce((desc, [key, value], i, arr) => {
           desc += key + ': ' + value + (i === arr.length - 1 ? '' : ' /n ');
           return desc;      
        }, '');
     return {...item, Description};
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original array:

```
let newList=
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small"},
{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000"},
{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock"}];
```

Desired result:

```
newList=
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small",
"Description":"Name: House 1 \n Type: Small"},

{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000",
"Description":"Name: House 2 \n Type: Big \n Rent: 3000"},

{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock",
"Description":"Name: House 3 \n Owner: Rock"}];
```

You can do this with:

```js
let newList=
[{"Name":"House 1","Type":"Small"},
{"Name":"House 2","Type":"Big","Rent":"3000"},
{"Name":"House 3","Owner":"Rock"}];

for( let x in newList ) {
    let el = newList[x];
    for( let m in el ) {
        if ( typeof newList[x]['Description'] == "undefined" ) {
            newList[x]['Description'] = "";
        } else {
            newList[x]['Description'] += " \n ";
        }
        newList[x]['Description'] += m + ": " + newList[x][m];
    }
}

console.log(newList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const finalList = newList.map((item) => ({
   ...item,
   description: Object.entries(item).reduce(
     (acc, [key, value], index, entries) => {
        return (
            acc + `${key} : ${value}${index < entries.length - 1 ? " \n " : 
        ""}`
        );
      },
       ""
     ),
}));
```